# Seat 5 men and 4 women in a row such that the women occupy even places

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

It is required to seat 5 men and 4 women in a row such that women occupy even places.  How many such arrangements are possible?

Comment: Since this is a site that encourages learning, you will get much more help if you show us what you have already done. Could you edit your question with your thoughts and ideas?

Answer (score 3):

For your question, women have to occupy the even places, so the men must occupy the odd places. Hence the number of arrangements is
$$4!\times5!$$